# Get notification info

Tags: java, android, notifications

I make the notification display and encounter a problem - some notifications do not have a title and text, for example, a player, some do not have anything in extras, like CleanMaster's notification about installing the application.

```
CharSequence title = (CharSequence)nf.extras.get("android.title");
CharSequence text = (CharSequence)nf.extras.get("android.text");
```

[image: Screenshot]